# Background service stops on removing app from app-tray

Tags: java, android

I have created a service which runs in background thread i.e it is continuing running when an app is closed but it is not working when I remove the app from recent apps (app-tray). In my Usecase I want the service to run even when I remove it from app_tray.

This is my code for service.

```
final class bgThreadClass implements Runnable{

    int service_id;

    bgThreadClass(int service_id){
        this.service_id=service_id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i=0;

        synchronized (this){
            while(i<10){
                i++;
                Log.d(TAG, "run: " +i);
                if(i==2){
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(MyService.this, Main3Activity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("Url", "someUrl");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                try {
                    wait(12000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            stopSelf(service_id);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you stopping your service in OnDestroy() method?

Comment: What do you mean by Background Service? Thread is not a service!

Comment: No, I am not stopping the service in OnDestroy() method.

Comment: Background service is because this is not running on main GUI thread.

Comment: Now I created a OnDestroy() method but didnt specified anything inside it. Still I am facing the same problem